# Random Friend using FQL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am right now using fql which brings all the friend list in array. Then I sort that array to get a random friend.

But it seems to take long time since i have to collect all the friends to get single random friend.

How do i go this in fql to get random friend?

```
SELECT uid, name, pic, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT uid, name, pic, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) order by rand() limit 1`

Comment: Glad you figure it out. 

You can still mark this answer as correct for future references if you like.