# Facebook API: get random friend with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to obtain a random friend. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465976/random-friend-using-fql) thread on SO and it looks it should work.
Here is my code:

```
            $config = array(
                'appId'  => APP_ID,
                'secret' => SECRET,
                'cookie' => true,
            );
            $facebook = new Facebook($config);

            $params = array(
                'method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' => "SELECT uid, name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) order by rand() limit 1",
            );

            $result = $facebook->api($params);
            echo print_r($result);
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 102: Requires user session thrown in /home/path/to/base_facebook.php on line 1050
```

Where is the problem? I've tried to search possible problem, but I wasn't much successful...

Comment: Do you have a FB login button? I think the issue is there is no authenticated user

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as Jason commented, looks like you've not got an authenticated user.

Since you're using the PHP SDK, the quickest way to fix this is as follows:

```
$config = array(
    'appId'  => APP_ID,
    'secret' => SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

// This will redirect the user to a login/authentication dialog.
if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
    echo "<script>window.location = '".$facebook->getLoginUrl()."'</script>";
    exit();
}

$params = array().. etc, the rest of your code
```

Lack of best practice code notwithstanding - That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your message Joe. Well, I have two pages - `index.php` and `data.php`. A user is on the start on the page `index.php` (the user is authenticated). From this page he send form (`action="data.php" method="get") and in this page (`data.php`) I would need to get a random user... Is there any way to pass the authenticated user from the page `index.php` to `data.php`? Thanks

Comment: Once they have logged in/authenticated the app, you can use the above code on the data.php page and it will work the same - it will only echo out the script if the $facebook->getUser() method fails.